# How to create Sorting/filtering for Content Search Web Part in SharePoint Online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, office365

I have used Content Search Web Part for one of the my Application. Using Display template, I have created a tabular format with the help of div and css. HTML Structure is like this:

```
<div class="rTable">
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead">
            Heading 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead">
            Heading 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">
            Cell 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">
            Cell 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to use Sorting & filtering in this Content Search Web Part (Or I can say, need to implement sorting for this HTML structure). Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using div structure, use Table structure. With table structure, it would be much easier to implement any kind of functionality like sorting, filtering, paging etc.

If transformation to table structure doesn't require too much efforts for your existing scenario, then i will recommended to change your HTML structure.

With table, you can use [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/) and it will fulfill your requirement.